# ReentrantLock y Condition

Tags: java, hilos

Alguien me podría explicar para que se usa `.newCondition` de la clase ´ReentrantLock´y `.await`de la interfaz `Condition`? y, ¿Como funciona internamente?

Comment: Está bastante bien explicado en [la documentación oficial de `Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). Lo dejo aquí más que nada para quien quiera tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Convendría que conozcas el significado de `wait`, `notify` e `interrupt` primero antes de revisar los mecanismos que se encuentran en `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: Está bien, voy a revisar los métodos y ver la doc.